# How to select the first element of a set with JSTL?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl

I managed to do it with the next code but there must be an easier way.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>


<c:if test="${fn:length(attachments) > 0}">
    <c:forEach var="attachment" items="${attachments}" varStatus="loopCount">
        <c:if test="${loopCount.count eq 1}">
         attachment.id
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Comment: the solution down as c:out used did not work I get the next error `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` i used you r code above since am using hibernate like this  `someobject.getSetofsomeObjects()` in request parameter

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can access individual elements with the array [] operator:

```
<c:out value="${attachments[0].id}" />
```

This will work for arrays and lists. It won't work for maps and sets. In that case you must put the key of the element inside the brackets.

Comment: I get the next error javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet

Comment: The above will only work for collections types that have a get(int i) method. Is this possible with PersistentSet?

Comment: For a `java.util.Set`, you need to convert it to an array first like `<c:out value="${bean.set.toArray()[0].propertyIfAny}" />`. A `java.util.Set` is an unordered list and it doesn't have an index like a `java.util.List`.

Comment: @kgiannakakis user asks how to access to Set thus answer is not relevent

Answer (score 38):

Sets have no order, but if you still want to get the first element you can use the following:

```
<c:forEach var="attachment" items="${attachments}" end="0">
     <c:out value="${attachment.id} />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 9):

Work for arrays and lists only, not for set.

Comment: well, the "aside" implementations are actually useful if you want unicity on top of ordering.

Answer (score 8):

Since i have have just one element in my Set the order is not important So I can access to the first element like this :

```
${ attachments.iterator().next().id }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2009/04/jstl-foreach-looping-tricks-using.html) for a description of the statusVar variable.
You can do something like below, where the "status" variable contains the current status of the iteration. This is very useful if you need special annotations for the first and last iteraton. In the case below I want to ommit the comma behind the last tag. Of course you can replace `status.last` with `status.first` to do something special on the first itteration:

```
<td>
    <c:forEach var="tag" items="${idea.tags}" varStatus="status">
        <span>${tag.name not status.last ? ', ' : ''}</span>
    </c:forEach>
</td>
```

Possible options are: **`current, index, count, first, last, begin, step,`** and **`end`**

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the **first** element of a set (and you are certain there is at least one element) you can do the following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${dealership.administeredBy.size() == 1}">
        Hello ${dealership.administeredBy.iterator().next().firstName},<br/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${dealership.administeredBy.size() > 1}">
        Hello Administrators,<br/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EL 3.0 Stream API.

```
<div>${attachments.stream().findFirst().get()}</div>
```

**Be careful!** The [EL 3.0 Stream API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/el/stream/Stream.html) was finalized before the [Java 8 Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) API and it is different than that. They can't sunc both apis because it will break the backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using ${mySet.toArray[0]} does not work.

I do not think it is possible without having forEach loop at least one iteration.

Comment: `${mySet.toArray[0]}` is a wrong syntax. The correct one would be `${mySet.toArray()[0].propertyIfAny}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using begin and end seemed to work for me to select a range of elements. This gives me three separate lists. The first list with items 1-9, second list with items 10-18, and the last list with items 11-25.

```
                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${actionBean.top25Teams}" begin="0" end="8" var="team" varStatus="counter">
                            <li>${team.name}</li>                               
                        </c:forEach> 
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${actionBean.top25Teams}" begin="9" end="17" var="team" varStatus="counter">
                            <li>${team.name}</li>                               
                        </c:forEach> 
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${actionBean.top25Teams}" begin="18" end="25" var="team" varStatus="counter">
                            <li>${team.name}</li>                               
                        </c:forEach> 
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a set `${attachments[0].id}` won't work. use this instead

`${attachments.first().key}` or `${attachments.first().value}`