# How do you get the first element in a collection in JSTL/EL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

My `container` contains multiple `widgets`.

I'm looping over them and **the `widgetcode` variable is set with the value of the last `widget` in the loop**.

**But what I really want is the first `widget` in the collection.**

How do I get this without looping?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(container.widgets) > 0}">
        <c:forEach items="${container.widgets}" var="widgetId" varStatus="status">
            <c:set var="widgetcode" value="/widget/<c:out value="${widgetId}"/>"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="widgetcode" value="/widget/000"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<c:set var="widgetcode" value="${container.widgets[0]}"/>
```

Comment: Note: this only works for indexed collections. Maps and Sets can't use this syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000876/557481