# jstl: how to know the variable? does it have some scope?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I just want use jstl:core with SpringMVC.

My controller contain something like :

```
private Map<UUID, ProductBean> products = new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, ProductBean>();
```

...
...
...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createproduct/{pbid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProduct(HttpServletRequest req, Model model, @PathVariable("pbid") UUID pbid) {
    if(!products.containsKey(pbid)){
        ProductBean tmp=new ProductBean();
        products.put(pbid, tmp);
        //model.addAttribute("product",tmp);
        System.err.println("============empty now===============\n");
    }else{
        ProductBean tmp=products.get(pbid);
        System.err.println(pbid.toString());
        System.err.println(tmp.getMpf().printFileNameList());
    }
    req.getSession().setAttribute("pbId", pbid);
    model.addAttribute("pbId", pbid);
    return "production/createproduct";
}
```

I want simple using jstl like:

```
    <c:choose>

                <c:when test="${products.get(pbId).getMpf().size()==0}">

                    <p>No pictures uploaded</p>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>

                    <ul id="products">
                                            ......
                    </ul>
                </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

But the program never go to the first branch

I added <%@ page import="java.util.*" language="java" %> package in my jsp, but it seems does not work. I follow the examples from http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-web-flow-subflow-webapp-jsp-example.html. It seems they also have variable not declare in jsp like ${persons}. I want the products variable can work both controller and jsp view part. what I need to do? where I should declare it? Do I need to include other packetage in my jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your controller has the following line commented out:

```
//model.addAttribute("product",tmp);
```

The JSP is looking for an object in the model named `products`. This is the default scope when referencing something via `${products}`. Since your controller is never adding an object with this name, it fails the `c:when`.

Additionally, for accessing list elements in JSTL, use the following notation:

```
${products[4]}
```

See [How to select the first element of a set with JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000876/how-to-select-the-first-element-of-a-set-with-jstl) for more detail on this.

Furthermore, you should not be using `.getXxx()` either. Assuming your object conforms to the [Javabean spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html), you reference items with just the name like follows:

```
${products[4].mpf}
```

Comment: I want use pbid instead I have model.addAttribute("pbId", pbid); When I want get product I use products.get(pbId) is that ok?

Comment: That's fine, you just need to add both objects (`products` and `pbId`) to the model. You will also have to use array notation (instead of get) to access the elements of a list in JSTL. I've edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: products object is not list,  it is a map.

Comment: Same thing applies... `${products['key']}`.