# How to do concatenation inside an EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I just want to do something like;

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="9" var="val">
  <input type="text"  value="${level${val}}">
</c:forEach>
```

What I want is `${level0}`, `${level1}`, ..., `${level9}` to have some values.

The code

```
<input type="text" value="${level0}">
```

will give me the value.

That I need to show for all by using a for loop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you put those elements in a list at the servlet level and just iterate over it?

Comment: I want to use "begin" and "end" in for loop, so i cant use "items".

Comment: You can still use the `varStatus` attribute to hold the loop index. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm). Just put 9 items in the list. **Or access the list by index instead. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000876/how-to-select-the-first-element-of-a-set-with-jstl)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In servlet

```
Level level1 = ...; 
Level level2 = ...;
...// more levels
List<Level> levels = ...// choose your favorite implementation
levels.add(level1);
levels.add(level2);
... // add all levels in order you want
request.setAttribute("levels", levels);
```

Then from the jsp

```
<c:forEach items="levels" var="level">
    <input type="text" value="${level}">
</c:forEach>
```