# How to get first element of list in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a java web application and one of the controllers creates a list. The list is then added to a model and passed to the jsp.

I can get all the elements of the list using the c:forEach etc...

However, how can I get JUST the first element of the list. I have looked around but cannot seem to find an example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000876/how-to-select-the-first-element-of-a-set-with-jstl)

```
<c:out value="${attachments[0].id}" />
```

Hope this helps.